# There's a problem while passing test in Testing your code

Tags: python, unit-testing

**In module name_function.py**

```
 def get_formatted_name(first,last):
     """Generate a neatly formatted full name"""
     full_name=f"{first} {last}"
     return full_name.title()
```

**In testing_name_function.py**

```
import unittest
from name_function import get_formatted_name
class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_first_last_name(self):
        formatted_name=get_formatted_name('tulasi','reddy')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name,'Tulasi Reddy')
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**But the Output which i got for passing the above test is**

```
E
ERROR: /data/data/ru (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '/data/data/ru'
Ran 1 test in 0.007s
FAILED (errors=1) 
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback. 
SystemExit: True
```

/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64linuxandroid/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3452: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

**Please help me to solve the error and i get passing test**

Comment: Running the tests on Python 3.9 on Windows works so I guess the issue is with IPython

Comment: So what should i do then